# How to replace part of str using `re.sub()`?

Tags: python, regex, python-2.7, regex-lookarounds

I can replace `oldText` with `newText1` as `re.sub("'(.*)'", 'newText', "test = 'oldText'")`
But I am trying to use `re.sub()` as `re.sub("'test = (.*)'", 'newText', "test = 'oldText'")`

Can I pass actual text in pattern?

I think numbers were bad example I updated with str. The first one works but second one doesn't. Isn't it allowed to have actual text in pattern?

Comment: The pattern `'test = (.*)'` will not match `test = '21'` because of the different quote position

Comment: Why have you tagged this a regex-lookaround? What is your desired result? Correcting your use of the single quote and the not using quotes around 22, you still are going to get the entire string replaced by '22'. Is that the desired result?

Comment: @dawg: Well, it does, since `.*` match all the things.

Comment: As noted above, your issues lie in a) proper use of quotes, b) confusion between int and str types. Please spend some time with simple examples or an re module tutorial page. Enjoy ;-)

Comment: it works the problem is when I add text in pattern, if I have only pattern it's fine

Comment: @user2661518: It's hard to understand what your problem is, please [edit] your question, and add more examples about what's your problem.

Comment: @KevinGuan: It [does not match](https://regex101.com/r/qQ6lO8/1) if, as the example is stated, the regex pattern starts with a `'` and the target text does not start with a single quote...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
>>> import re
>>> 
>>> re.sub(r"(test = )'.*'", r"\1'" + str(22) + r"'", "test = '21'")
"test = '22'"
```

You can do it but you need to grab all the other parts of the match and piece it back together with the new result.

Comment: Yes, it's called a back reference.  You can have one for each set of parens, within reason.